Prime-Independence of p-adic Continued Fractions: New Observation?
I've recently been exploring p-adic continued fractions and stumbled upon an intriguing pattern. It seems that the p-adic continued fraction representations of rational numbers are consistent across different primes. I wanted to share this observation and seek feedback from the community.
For instance, the p-adic continued fraction for $\frac{1}{2}$ appears identical for primes 2, 3, 5, and 7:

Prime 2: $[0, 2]$
Prime 3: $[0, 2]$
Prime 5: $[0, 2]$
Prime 7: $[0, 2]$

This pattern holds across other rational numbers and primes as well. Here are additional examples:

$\frac{3}{4}$ for primes 2, 3, 5, 7:

$[0, 1, 3, 1125899906842624]$


$\frac{7}{8}$ for primes 2, 3, 5, 7:

$[0, 1, 7, 281474976710656]$



I've extended the analysis to a larger set of rational numbers and primes (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29) and observed the same pattern. The results consistently suggest a prime-independent property of p-adic continued fractions.
Is this prime-independence property of p-adic continued fractions a known phenomenon? If not, I'd appreciate any insights or feedback from the community. Could there be a theoretical basis for this observation, or is it an area worth exploring further?
Edit 1: Based on feedback, I want to clarify that the algorithm used for generating these p-adic continued fractions is a basic iterative method. Different algorithms might yield different results, and I plan to explore these further.
Edit 2: I explored different algorithms (Browkin I, Browkin II, and Improved Algorithm) for generating p-adic continued fractions. The prime-independence holds for Browkin I and the Improved Algorithm but not for Browkin II, indicating that the observed property is algorithm-dependent.
Thank you for your time and insights!

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

Thanks for letting me know. I believe the formatting issues are fixed.

It might be worth indicating in your post how you are deriving continued fractions for p-adic numbers. For example, it seems – example link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.05252 – that there isn't a single agreed upon algorithm for generating these representations. If the method you're using has the same output for multiple numbers (including 1/2 when viewed 2-adically and 3-adically, 5-adically, etc?) then probably it is not an optimal approach.

Hi Benjamin,
Thanks for the feedback! I used a basic iterative algorithm for generating the p-adic continued fractions. I see your point about different algorithms yielding varied results. I'll explore other methods like Browkin's and the improved algorithm from the paper you mentioned to see if the prime-independence still holds.
Appreciate the insight!

$1125899906842624$??? That really looks like some kind of round-off error. The usual continued fraction for $3/4$ is just $[0,1,3]$. Does that not work $p$-adically?

Thank you for pointing that out. It does seem that there was an issue with the previous results. I rechecked the calculations for  3/4 using the Browkin I, Browkin II, and Improved Algorithm, and they all correctly yield [0, 1, 3] The earlier result with the large number was indeed an error.
Thanks for your help!

Please make this question more self-contained by describing how to derive a $p$-adic continued fraction (at least one algorithm, at least roughly), and why one would expect it to depend on $p$ for some rational numbers. The arxiv article linked in comments above uses that p is odd, so I am already at a loss what you would have checked for $p=2$.

That being said, your three examples are of the form $\frac{2^n−1}{2^n}$
which are special in several ways. They also allow generalizations in various ways that you can check yourself if you enjoy that.
